# Function to iterate two different dataframes and fill a column if condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, for-loop

I'm new to writing functions in python and will appreciate some help on this front:

Problem Statement:

I have two dataframes - `df1` & `df2`. Both the dataframes have a shared column (lets call it `Name`), but the dataframes are of different length. I need to write a function that fills a value in `df1` if the name exists in `df2`.

```
>>> df1
Name 1 2 3
A
B
C
D
```

```
>>> df2
Name
B
D
```

Value to input in column 3 of df1 = YES

```
New df1
Name 1 2 3
A        
B         YES
C
D         YES
```

My attempt at the function so far:

```
def fillerfunc(df1, df2, Index_Column, value):
    for i, row in df1.iterrows():
        df1.iloc[i,Index_Column] = np.select([df1['Name'].isin(df2)], value, np.nan)
```

Hoping to implement this as:

```
df1['3'] = fillmodel(df1, df2, 3, YES)

ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

I understand the error is probably about df1 & df2 having different lengths. But I think my function is wrong in other areas too. Help & pointers so I can learn how to do this will be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with boolean indexing.

```
df1.loc[df1.Name.isin(df2.Name), '3'] = 'Yes'
```

Or if your column `3` is a numeric column name:

```
df1.loc[df1.Name.isin(df2.Name), 3] = 'Yes'
```

Comment: Thank you James! I made a small modification in my code - used iloc instead of loc because i wanted to use '3' as index of column.